# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111) ERROR: Can't connect to the server

Tags: mysql

```html
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| anunturi           |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use anunturi;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    3
Current database: anunturi

ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR: 
Can't connect to the server
```

не могу зайти в БД anunturi. Погуглил не нашел
ОС Linux 4.4.0-155-generic (i686)
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux (i686) using  EditLine wrapper

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, заранее спасибо

Comment: Проверьте, работает ли `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'anunturi'`. Проверьте, есть ли у учётной записи права на эту БД.

Comment: mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'anunturi';
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    3
Current database: anunturi

ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR: 
Can't connect to the server

Comment: Как насчёт того же, но с другой БД? а хоть бы и `mysql`?

Comment: mysql> use mysql;
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    3
Current database: *** NONE ***

Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql           |
+---------------------------+
| columns_priv              |
| db                        |
| engine_cost               |
| event                     |
| func                      |
| general_log            .....
31 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Выгрузите MySQL. Проверьте файловую систему. Загрузите MySQL и смотрите лог загрузки.

Comment: извините за вопрос - как выгрузить и загрузить mysql

Comment: Это Ваша убунта - вот и смотрите, как в ней стопнуть или стартануть демон сервера. Я - понятия не имею...

Comment: у вас есть возможность через teamviewer зайти? поскольку я сам не разберусь

Comment: Нет смысла, я с юниксами на "ой, что это?"...

Comment: есть еще какие-то идеи?